# Iterate over Json array on the basis of keys, Key are dynamic and fetched first

Tags: json

I am struggling with the JSON data,Here, I first fetched the keys, As the keys could be random. After that I would like to iterate in the array the Key.

```
<script>
var text = '{"name":["John Johnson", "Cool", "Bay", "Life"],"street":["yyy", "xxx", " 1x"],"phone":["5xx", "12xxx7"]}';

var obj = JSON.parse(text);
var key = Object.keys(obj);
document.write("Keys :" +key);
```

I got the Keys from the above code now I would like to iterate through the values on the basis of keys, for which I wrote the code below but it is not working as expected.

```
for(i in key){
   document.write("<br>Key:"+key[i]);
   var key1 = key[i];
   //document.write(obj.key1);
   for(j in key1){
       document.write("-->"+key1[j]);
   }
}
```

I am not sure How to do this. Kindly Help.

Answer (score 0):

In your for loop, replace in with of and that will give you the key name as a string.

You can then do `obj[key]` to get the value:

```
var obj = JSON.parse(text);
var keys = Object.keys(obj);

for(key of keys)
{
    var val = obj[key];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are almost there.

What you need to do is iterate over the original object (not the array of keys). To do this, instead of

```
var key1 = key[i];
```

use

```
var key1 = obj[key[i]];
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this :**

```js
var text = '{"name":["John Johnson", "Cool", "Bay", "Life"],"street":["yyy", "xxx", " 1x"],"phone":["5xx", "12xxx7"]}';

var obj = JSON.parse(text);
var key = Object.keys(obj);

for(var i in key){
   console.log(key[i]+ ":");
   var key1 = obj[key[i]];
   for(j in key1){
     console.log("      "+key1[j]);
   }
}
```